# copy lines data between 2 patterns in shell scripting

Tags: shell, sed, grep

This is my source.php file i want copy line number and line code if pattern matches between **'<(single quot less than)** and **'>;(sinle quot greater than comma)**

[image]

This is destination.php file i want output like this

[image]

line no... 18,19,29 should not print....becaus it not match B/T pattern..so how to remove this....any suggetion

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want to extract portions of code from `source.php` to copy into `destination.php`? If so, which lines?

Comment: yes i copy line between patter match '<(single quot lessthan) and '>;(single quot greater than coma) and i try this grep -noP "(?<='<).*(?='>;)" < source.php >> destination.php

Comment: update your question to show the expected output given that sample input.

Comment: i use this sed -ne "/'</,/>'\;/wdestination.php" source.php so code copy right way but i also copy begining of line with line number like show in snapshot of destination.php file

Answer (score 1):

if you want to copy all lines that happens to be between '< and >'; into the destination.php :

```
sed -ne "/'</,/>'\;/wdestination.php" source.php
```

Comment: thnks sidharth code copy done but i want copy same line number also for pattern match from source file....i mean code copy done but in begining of line i want line nuber which match from source file

Comment: sed -ne "/'</,/>'\;/{=;p}" source.php | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;wdestination.php'    hope this is what you are looking for +

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
sed -ne "/'</,/>'\;/{=;p}" source.php | sed '/./N;s/\n/ /' > wdestination.php
```

The `=` prints the line number of the pattern. The second `sed` command puts the line number on the same line as the text, otherwise it would be printed on separate lines.

Comment: nothing print in destination .php file..can u give code only for line number print if pattern match?

Comment: does this print anything for you? `sed -ne "/'</,/>'\;/{=;p}" source.php`

Comment: yes match line number and matched line with new line i want same line

Comment: does this print anything for you? `sed -ne "/'</,/>'\;/{=;p}" source.php | sed '/./N;s/\n/ /'`

Comment: @dogbane....i will update the screen shot for output in my answer ....can u please check

Comment: check myupdate in question with screen-shot ...please give suggestion