# extract matched line with line number between two pattern

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

Is  it  possible  to copy line with line number to destinationphp file for  pattern match using sed, awk or grep? Take for example,
 I would like to copy  all the lines with line number   between **'<(single quot less than)** and **'>;(single quot greater than comma)** from source.php file to destination.php

this is source.php [image]

i have code 
  **sed  -ne "/''\;/wdestination.php" source.php**

thats output look in screenshot
[image]

but i want copy matched line number in begining of line  with line data
look like in next screenshot 
[image]

Comment: instead of screenshots, you should paste your code into the question so that we can use your code to test our solutions.

Comment: Exact duplication of OP last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810814/copy-lines-data-between-2-patterns-in-shell-scripting

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -ne "/'</,/>'\;/{=;p}" source.php | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;wdestination.php'
```

hope this is what you are looking for +

Comment: yes it works but look question in middle screenshot line number 9,10,11 which also print ...which is not match my pattern

Comment: hi..sidharth ..can i add : symbol between line number and line data same as third screenshot??

Comment: sed -ne "/'</,/>'\;/{=;p}" source.php | sed 'N;s/\n/ :/;wdestination.php'    this will add : symbol

Comment: plz look line number 9,10,11 in middle screenshot which is not match between two pattern then also print how to handle this??

Comment: awk " /'</ {printme = 1}; printme {print NR; print} ; />';/ {printme =0} " source.php | sed 'N;s/\n/ : /' > destination.php

Comment: how to run awk in cygwin terminal ...i add this code to .sh file but error occur for gawk.exe

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk " /'</ {printme = 1}; printme {print NR; print} ; />';/ {printme =0} " source.php | sed 'N;s/\n/ : /' > destination.php
```

see if this works +